# Unable to iterate through e-mail objects using powershell in Outlook

Tags: powershell, scripting, outlook

I'm writing a script, which takes Outlook folder as input and moves every unread mail to different folder. My code:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$olFolderInbox = 6
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

$myFolder  = $namespace.pickfolder() 

$toFolder = $inbox.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "UnreadMessages" }
$messages = $myFolder.Items
$messageCount = $messages.count

for ($i = $messageCount - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--) 
{
    if ($messages[$i].unread -eq $True)
    {
         $message.move($toFolder)
    }
 }
```

The problem is, that I can not iterate through "messages" objects. Error:
Unable to index into an object of type `System.__ComObject`.

If it's not possible, then how am I supposed to do it? 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT. It's my first day using powershell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you **cannot use PowerShell's usual indexing syntax** - `$messages[$i]` -
 for accessing the elements of `$messages`, you can **use `.Items($i)`** on the *folder* object (see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863652.aspx)):

Additionally, as noted in [Dmitry Streblechenko's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43741751/45375), indices start at `1`, not `0`:

```
for ($i = $myFolder.Items.Count; $i -ge 1; $i--) 
{
    $message = $myFolder.Items($i)
    if ($message.unread)
    {
       $message.move($toFolder)
    }
 }
```

For simple **forward enumeration without indices** you can **use `foreach`**:

```
foreach ($message in $myFolder.Items) {
    if ($message.unread)
    {
       $message.move($toFolder)
    }
 }
```

(`$myFolder.Items | ForEach-Object { ... }` should work too, but it will be slower.)

That said, [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43741751/45375) answer also points to how to perform a *filtered* enumeration *at the source*, which performs much better.

Answer (score 2):

All Outlook collections are 1 based, not 0 - you need to iterate from `Items.Count` down to 1.

Secondly, do not just iterate through **all** messages in a folder, use `Items.Find`/`FindNext`. In your case, the search criteria would be `"[Unread] = true"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a get-member on it, and see what your options are.

```
$Messages | Get-Member -force
```

If you figure out how you want to proceed, then you can use the ForEach-Object to loop through $Messages' content like this

```
$Messages | ForEach-Object { Script code }
```

Or use its abbreviation:

```
$Messages | % { Script code }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. All your answers were helpful. I finally used foreach loop. While I was trying to use `$message = $myFolder.Items($i)` following error appeared:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't cont
ain a method named 'Items'
```

so there is no possibility to iterate using indexes in this case.

Thank You all for your time :)